# How do you utilize a third-party iOS SDK with your Appcelerator Titanium app?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

We have a well established iOS (iPad only) app written on top of Appcelerator's Titanium platform. We're looking to integrate a third-party piece of hardware with our app that interfaces with the headphone jack on the iPad. The third-party company provides an official iOS SDK to be used in XCode projects.

How can we get the provided SDK to work in our Titanium app?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a module. Check the guide [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide).

You can also search the internet. There might be existing modules already for your third-party SDK.